# Working with dates in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date-format, datefield

How do I process a date that is input by the user and store it in the database in a date field? The date is entered by the user using a jquery datepicker in a text field.

Here are specific needs I have:
1. How do you convert a mm/dd/yy string (the jquery picked can produce any format) to a format storable in the database as a date field.
2. How to get the date and then change it to something like "Wednesday, Aug 11, 2009"?

I'm using C# for the backend, but I should be able to understand VB Code as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`DateTime.Parse(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) to parse the string to a `DateTime` which can then be saved as a `DateTime` in the database. You may want to use TryParse as suggested in other answers, to ensure that the supplied string can be parsed to a `DateTime`.

To return a DateTime in a certain format, you can call .ToString() on the DateTime and [supply a format](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) or use one of the pre-defined formats e.g. [`ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - this explained it really quickly to me!

Answer (score 7):

```
string dateString = "08/11/09";
DateTime yourDate;

if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out yourDate)) 
{
   // do something with yourDate
   string output = yourDate.ToString("D"); // sets output to: Tuesday, August 11, 2009
}
else 
{
   // invalid date entered
}
```

Here is a list of `DateTime` format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the example! I slowly understood that it answered both parts after seeing Russ's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with John Rasch's solution. What people often don't know is that you can also use the `String.Format(...)` method to format your date (and other data types). For dates it is obviously more convenient to use the T`oString()` method, since the date provides such functionality, but other data types will probably return you the object's address in the `ToString()`.

So given you get your date from the DB or somewhere as DateTime object you can do the following:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; //normally would come from somewhere else

//Wednesday, Aug 11, 2009 <-- what we want to get displayed
string displayFormat ="dddd, MMM dd, yyyy";
string formattedDate = string.Format("{0:" + displayFormat + "}", date);

Response.Write(formattedDate);
```

This will exactly print what you requested. The explanation of the different format strings can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip that it works mainly for the date data type.

Answer (score 1):

cDate(string) will give you a actual date from a string, and dateformat(string,option) will return a string formatted as the option states - longdateformat is one of the options that I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers will check to see that it is a date (although i do a `try` `catch` block to do it)
Once you have confirmed the string to be a date, you can just pass it to a stored procedure or put it in single quotes and make it part of your insert/update statement:

```
string yourdateString ="5-5-09";

update table set da='" + yourDateString + "' WHERE id=@id
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter which format you parsed your DateTime field

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;//*example
//FormatString for "Wednesday, Aug 11, 2009" is *dddd,MMM dd,yyyy*
string formattedString = dt.ToString("dddd,MMM dd,yyyy");
```

You can globally hold this format and use it